# strange fopen() behavior; giving unexpected NULL in case A and works perfect in similar case B

Tags: c++, file, null, fopen, bin

I am baffled with the way fopen() is responding to my code. Note that I am using it to write binary files read from FPGA. The scenario is this

1. When I WRITE data to FPGA based system and then read back (after processing), only 307 files in binary can be saved, after which the fopen() returns NULL value
2. When I only read from FPGA (no writing at all) then it saves perfectly in all the 500 files.
3. When I do both cases for writing in .txt files, every thing goes perfect

CASE 1 is my problem and the real-world implementation I need. Hence I cannot understand this strange behaviour. One thing is assured with several testing that the whole problem is with the PC/C++ side and FPGA has nothing to do with it.

The first code is the calling of function, the second code is the function for writing binary files itself

```
...
sprintf(fwname, "data/uwpi%d.bin", fnum++); 
opfile = fopen(fwname , "w");
rc = sipif_readdata(pInDMA, (40000)*2); 
save_binary(pInDMA,  40000, fwname, opfile , fnum);
...
```

The following is the function details

```
static ULONG save_binary(void *buf, int bufsize, const char *filename, FILE *fOutFile, int fnum){   

// cast our stamp less pointer to a short
short *buf16 = (short *)buf;

fOutFile = fopen(filename, "ab");
if(fOutFile==NULL) {
    //comment added to verify my claim
    printf("Null value found at file %d\n", fnum);
    return -3;  }   

printf("fnum is %d\n", fnum);
fwrite(buf, 2, bufsize, fOutFile);
fclose(fOutFile);
return 0;
```

}

[image]

Comment: Note that case 1 and 2 are related which made me baffled since both are for binary file saving, but in case 1, I have FPGA write/Read both, while is case 2 I have only FPGA read (from the data already processed in FPGA-based system)

Comment: You look like you're double-opening each output file - you pass a file handle in to `save_binary` but ignore it and open the file again. If you're failing to close the handle you opened outside the `save_binary` function then you'll be leaking handles. There's a maximum number of files that can be open at any one time in the standard C/C++ library.

Comment: @JonathanPotter : Thank you. It was the case as you mentioned. If you would have answer as the  reply, instead of comment I could post it as the solution. :) but anyways....It was very silly of me ignoring it that I was opening file twice....